# Passing variables between multiple functions in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pass-by-reference

so i have some code which looks like this :

```
var my_important_var_x = 'init'; // my global variable for storing one very important piece of info. [screen size/resolution]

function checkmyresolutin() {
   // this tests the broswer/window resolution and print to the body [for css purposes]
  var resolution_is = '768px';
  my_important_var_x = resolution_is; // now the var contains the resolution

  return my_important_Var_X;
}

checkmyresolutin(); // for getting the resolutoin on document ready.

$(window).resize(function(){
   checkmyresolutin();  // this is the important part,every time the browser is resized i need to know ,certain function load/unload on certain resolutions.
});

function_abc(); // this is my problem,ill explain bellow,to keep this code block clean.
```

So after the `checkmyresolutin()` is called when the browser is resized and it returns the resolution/sceensize and is stored in the `my_important_var_x` variable ,i need to pass that latest information from that variable to the `function_abc();` function...anyone ?

EDIT :

Guys,there are typos but ignore them,i did not copy paste my .js,becasuse it would take up to 400 lines,this is just an ***example*** ,the "logic" is what's important here.

I just need somehow to pass content of the `enter code here` to the `function_abc()` after the `checkmyresolutin()` has been run by the jQuery `resize function()`

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Right now you don't need to pass anything; the variable is a global.

Comment: Just call `function_abc()` from the `resize` handler as well?

Comment: `my_important_Var_X` -vs- `my_important_var_X` ?

Comment: @TimVermaelen typo...sorry

Comment: @Bergi can't,must be like this.

Comment: Sorry, the `resize` handler will run in the future. You just can't do that. You could of course create an event stream (that emits resolution events), and pass that to `function_abc`.

Comment: @Aca85 You seem to be saying you want to pass the value to the function without calling the function - what would you expect that to do?

Comment: Please don't tell us to ignore typos, but rather fix them. The better (easier to understand) your question is, the more likely we will help you. Incomprehensible, long-winded questions get downvoted and eventually closed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

`var my_important_var_x = 'init'; // my global variable for storing one very important piece of info. [screen size/resolution]`

should be

`var my_important_Var_X = 'init'; // my global variable for storing one very important piece of info. [screen size/resolution]`

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g5vLgqm/), with an annoying alert, to show it working.

I also made [a different version](http://jsfiddle.net/8g5vLgqm/1/) where function_abc() is called automatically on resize, just to show how that works.

Check out [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) of variable scope in Javascript.